# Android Using Parcelable gives error : android.os.Parcel unmarshelling unknown type code

Tags: android

```
public class GalleryDTO  implements Parcelable{

private String id;
private String title;
private String date;
private String featuredDesc;
private String bodyText;
private String thumbnailURL;
private String featuredPictureURL;
private String fullPictureURL;


public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public GalleryDTO createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new GalleryDTO(in);
    }


    public GalleryDTO[] newArray(int size) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

};

public GalleryDTO(){

}

public GalleryDTO(Parcel in){
    readFromParcel(in);

}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    id = in.readString();

    title = in.readString();
    bodyText = in.readString();
    thumbnailURL = in.readString();
    date = in.readString();
    featuredDesc = in.readString();
    featuredPictureURL = in.readString();
    fullPictureURL = in.readString();
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getFeaturedDesc() {
    return featuredDesc;
}
public void setFeaturedDesc(String featuredDesc) {
    this.featuredDesc = featuredDesc;
}
public String getBodyText() {
    return bodyText;
}
public void setBodyText(String bodyText) {
    this.bodyText = bodyText;
}

public String getThumbnailURL() {
    return thumbnailURL;
}


public void setThumbnailURL(String thumbnailURL) {
    this.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL;
}


public String getFeaturedPictureURL() {
    return featuredPictureURL;
}


public void setFeaturedPictureURL(String featuredPictureURL) {
    this.featuredPictureURL = featuredPictureURL;
}


public String getFullPictureURL() {
    return fullPictureURL;
}


public void setFullPictureURL(String fullPictureURL) {
    this.fullPictureURL = fullPictureURL;
}

public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.bodyText);
    dest.writeString(this.date);
    dest.writeString(this.featuredDesc);
    dest.writeString(this.fullPictureURL);
    dest.writeString(this.thumbnailURL);
    dest.writeString(this.title);       

}
```

}

i put the parcelable in my activioty here

```
 private ArrayList galleryArray;


  public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    Bundle appData = new Bundle();
    appData.putParcelableArrayList("galleryVector",
            (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) galleryArray);

    startSearch(null, false, appData, false);
    return true;

}
```

in my searchableActivity i did like this

```
  Bundle appData = intent.getBundleExtra(SearchManager.APP_DATA);

        if (appData != null) {
            galleryItems = appData.getParcelable("galleryVector");
        }
```

and it throws error  "android.os.Parcel  unmarshelling unknown type code" while getting the parcelable out of the parcel.....

can u help me where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have to use `appData.getParcelableArrayList()` instead of `appData.getParcelable()`. You are putting in with `putParcelableArrayList()` so you have to retrieve the data with the corresponding method, i.e. `getParcelableArrayList`.